# Using PostgreSQL 8.4, how to convert bytea to text value in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, encoding, postgresql-8.4, string, bytea

In my application I insert data in database using C code, since the strings I receive from an untrusted source I have escaped them using `PQescapeByteaConn` of libpq library. Which is working perfectly fine i.e. results in Octet format String. See below example,

Input String : `\n\t\f\b\p\k\j\l\mestPrepared`

Output String : `\\012\\011\\014\\010pkjlmestPrepared`

Output String is inserted in the database. Now I retrieve that data from the database in a java code using JDBC. How I can unescape the string back to its original value ?

I thought of two possible approaches,

1. Change the database retrieval query and pass this field to any String manipulation function of postgres i.e. which can convert bytea to text.
2. Do the decoding in Java code.

I can understand that the approach 1 will be more efficient. I have tried almost all the functions listed [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html#CONVERSION-NAMES) but nothing is working. Please Help!!

I am using version 8.4 of postgres on a linux machine.

Comment: The JDBC driver is supposed to decode bytea. What's wrong with `ResultSet.getBytes()`?

Comment: @DanielVérité I will try that and let you know about that

Answer (score 37):

For followers, since this seems to be the canonical question for "converting bytea to text" (i.e. so you can actually see it in pgAdmin etc.) . Here's how to just get it viewable (assuming `your_column_name` is
type `bytea`)

`select encode(table.your_column_name, 'escape') as your_alias_name from table_name`

Comment: How would you reverse this? Simply `decode(..., 'escape')`?

Comment: Looks like yes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49926257/32453

Answer (score 20):

Have you tried the `encode(data bytea, format text)` with `escape` format. In that syntax `format` can be any of these,

- base64
- hex
- escape

So `encode(E'123\\000456'::bytea, 'hex')` will output the bytea as hex-encoded.

Comment: This should be a comment on the question, unless you are sure it solves the problem.  If it does solve the problem, can you elaborate on why and how this works for the benefit of future readers?

Comment: @Valgog I have already tried that..

Answer (score 16):

Converting BYTEA to TEXT requires you to know the internal encoding of the text. Without knowing the encoding, there is nothing you can do. In a normal `text` column, the database stores the text as whatever `SERVER_ENCODING` is set as. For instance, in your example `\n` gets translated into `\012`. Well, that's a property of encoding. It's not objectively true for the universe.

If you know that encoding, it's simple however..

1. We take your input string as an encoded literal.
2. We [`encode`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-string.html) it. This produces an escaped string (type `text`).
3. Then we have to decode it back to get a type of `bytea`.
4. Now having a `bytea` doesn't permit us to go back to `text`. We have to tell it what text format that `bytea` is in using [`convert_from`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-string.html). We tell it UTF-8.

Here is an example.

```
SELECT convert_from(decode(x, 'escape'), 'UTF-8')
FROM encode(E'\n\t\f\b\p\k\j\l\mestPrepared'::bytea, 'escape')
  AS t(x);
```