# How can I import CSV data stored in a bytea?

Tags: postgresql, import, postgresql-9.6, copy

I have a CSV file that can be loaded into a table easily with [`COPY FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html), but the catch is that the file is stored in the database in a `bytea` field.

Is the only way to use `COPY` on this data to write it out to a temporary file, or is there some clever trick, perhaps involving `COPY FROM STDIN`?

Answer (score 1):

## Precaution

The only reason I can see storing a CSV as a `bytea` is if you created it with [`COPY TO BINARY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html). You'll want to check to make sure this isn't binary data. If so the whole question is a off the mark as you don't have to do this and can just feed the bytea to `COPY FROM STDIN`

## Using `convert_from`

The question is mostly how do you convert a `bytea` to `text`. To do that you'll use [`convert_from`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html). See my answer [here for more information on that process](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/174512/2639).

After you have a method to get the `bytea` to `text` you can either,

- Wrap a `psql -d myDb -c "SELECT convert_from(col ...) FROM tbl"` in a call to `COPY FROM STDIN` and make use of it.
- Parse it from within the `INSERT`/`UPDATE` using *something* that can process a CSV-row (suggest `Text_CSV::XS`). Doing it this way will save you from having to call a second a session to read and output in a format that `COPY` can accept.

Comment: "The only reason I can see storing a CSV as a bytea" storing it as a blob ensures there is no mucking around with encoding, but yes, I take you point, thanks.

Comment: @JackDouglas that argument could be used for any text stored from an external source. In all cases, I personally would rather re-encode as UTF8 if we're just talking about text, and store as UTF8.

Comment: I meant 'encoding' broadly, not just character encoding but stuff like newlines etc. binary guarantees the file isn't tampered with in any way at all