# How to convert a bytea column to text?

Tags: postgresql, bytea

**how to convert a bytea  column to text in PostgreSQL so that I can read the column properly in PGADMIN?**

I have the following SQL query in the PGADMIN's query editor:

```
SELECT event_type, created_at, encode(metadata::bytea, 'escape') 
FROM public.events 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 100
```

However, it produces an `encoded` column with each records more or less ressembling the following output:

```
\203t\00000some_textd\000some_other_textd\0000
```

How can I get rid of this encoded, so that I only see the original value of the column, in the text format:

```
some_text some_data
```

What I have also tried:

```
SELECT event_id, event_type, created_at, decode((encode(metadata, 'escape')::text), 'escape')
FROM public.events
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 100
```

But in the above case, the query returns a `decode` column of type `bytea` and I only see the field `[binary data]` for each record of the column.

I have also tried the first two answers mentioned [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/using-postgresql-8-4-how-to-convert-bytea-to-text-value-in-postgres) without success and can't properly translate the last [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/174512/213407) to my query.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I finally found out how to display a `bytea` column as a text!
I can use the function `convert_from` like so:

```
SELECT event_type, convert_from(metadata, 'UTF8') as metadata
FROM public.events 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Then I'll have the metadata column in a human-readable format.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get rid of this encoded, so that I only see the original
> value of the column, in the text format

Bytes have 256 possible values, when there are only about 95 visualizable ASCII characters, (the range [32:126]), so the mapping between ASCII text and binary representation cannot be one-to-one.

The format produced by `encode(metadata::bytea, 'escape')` is just one possible representation, where some bytes are represented by sequences of characters. Others common representations are hexadecimal (outputs each byte as 2 characters) and base64 (outputs each 3 bytes as 4 characters).

If you don't want these and have a specific idea on how your `metadata` column should be output as text, then you can always provide a user function instead of  `encode`. Right now your question does not specify what output you want to see, only that it's not the `escape` format.